# Is "homestead transition" block needed in chainspec for a private network?

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, homestead

In the `chainspec.json` file for a custom chain, there is this value:

> "homesteadTransition": "0x30d40",

Do I need that if I'm running on a private blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be using the most up-to-date codepaths - e.g. those that don't make your chain function like it's currently still in the old Frontier phase - then you can set this value to `0`.

The only really relevant piece of code is found [here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/35958a09658d0aec37200ca2881970cb7ac7f7e3/ethcore/src/ethereum/ethash.rs#L193), in `ethash.rs`. You may want to consider how you'd like your chain to function with regards to the EIP transitions as well, and configure the chain spec file accordingly.

```
            block_number >= self.ethash_params.eip160_transition,
            block_number >= self.ethash_params.eip161abc_transition,
            block_number >= self.ethash_params.eip161d_transition,
            block_number >= self.params.eip86_transition
```

(I'm suspecting you'll want the code associated with these to be active, in which case you can set these values to `0` as well.)